# Turning off Prisma migrations and db push for a certain project

Tags: node.js, prisma

I am working with a system with multiple services, in this system Prisma is used to handle the entire database management.

I was wondering if there is a way to turn of certain features of the prisma ORM system for a project.
Basically, I don't want the project to be able to run commands that alter the schema/structure of the database, I only want it to be used as a data read/write tool.

In basic terms, I want to "turn off":

- `npx prisma migrate dev`
- `npx prisma db push`

Thanks in advance.